# What is the most idiomatic way to pass a setState callback?

Tags: flutter, dart

When you're using `setState()` for state management, it's common to pass setState callbacks to your widget's constructors.

Right now, I'm passing them like this:

```
MyWidget(redrawParentWidget: () { setState(() {}); });
```

Which is quite verbose. Is there a more succint way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used that technique, but it seems to me that it would be cleaner to use a named method:

```dart
void updateState() => setState(() {});

...

MyWidget(redrawParentWidget: updateState);
```

especially if your parent widget might want to do this with multiple child widgets.  If your `updateState` methods will all be identical, you probably could use a `mixin` to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

When you can use the Arrow Function as:

```dart
MyWidget(redrawParentWidget: () => setState(() {}));
```

Arrow Functions are a one-line alternative for lambda functions.

```dart
() { 
  return 2;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```dart
() => 2;
```

Pay attention to the hidden `return` statement, some people tend to forget it sometimes.